# kill processes one by one using .bat

Tags: windows, batch-file

I want to kill process "example.exe" one by one or two at a time to eventually get 0 "example.exe" processes
and loop check if there's any "example.exe" processes every minute , if there is - terminate them/it.
Right now I'm using this

```
:TASKKILL 
TASKKILL /F /IM WerFault.exe
ping 1.1.1.1 -n 1 -w 120000
goto :TASKKILL
```

but this just kills them all at the same time which is no good to me .

Comment: I guess you could use `tasklist`, pick out the ID of the first matching process, then kill just that one.

Comment: Thing is , I can have from 1 to 128 of this same process and I think the PID always changes , it has to be done by name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this snippet in a batch file:

```
:KillWerFault
set PID=
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist /fi "IMAGENAME eq WerFault.exe" /nh') do set PID=%%x
if not defined PID goto :Done
taskkill /f /pid %PID%
timeout /t 1 /nobreak>nul
goto :KillWerFault

:Done
echo All dead.
```

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens, oh actually it is . it was my bad , Thank you :D

Comment: Glad it's working for you, and welcome to SO.  Make sure you mark this as answered so it can help others, too.